# Shared array in rails ruby threads on Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, thread-safety, nginx

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8 and my problem is as follows:-

I have to call 6 different web services via AJAX to get results and in the end all of the results are populated in one global array. Results from these web services are returned usually at random times ( all of these web services usually return results within 6 to 15 seconds).

I am using one global array say @@cars to save the results generated. Whenever, one of the ajax call finishes its processing it finds out the @@cars to be nil.

This works fine locally on the development machine with mongrel but on nginx its creating issues.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is really not what global variables are for and I'm not surprised it's not working reliably when using this technique. You should consider putting the data elsewhere (be it a normal database, or something like redis which would be well suited to simple array storage). That way, the data is less associated to the different threads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, in my case, i have to query the web services to get the required result and after performing some extraction over that data i make it available for the users. I don't really have to save that data as it changes/validity changes in a few hours.  This seems problem with nginx and ruby rails. Seems like nginx is not threadsafe with rails and there are no work around to this problem?